# Why am I getting this error? (Bundler::HTTPError)

Tags: rubygems

Why am I getting this error when trying to do "bundle install" ?
The status page at ruby gems org doesn't indicate any incidents fyi.

```
$ bundle
The dependency tzinfo-data (>= 0) will be unused by any of the platforms Bundler is installing for. Bundler is installing for ruby but the dependency is only for x86-mingw32, x86-mswin32, x64-mingw32, java. To add those platforms to the bundle, run `bundle lock --add-platform x86-mingw32 x86-mswin32 x64-mingw32 java`.
Fetching source index from https://rubygems.org/

Retrying fetcher due to error (2/4): Bundler::HTTPError Could not fetch specs from https://rubygems.org/
Retrying fetcher due to error (3/4): Bundler::HTTPError Could not fetch specs from https://rubygems.org/
Retrying fetcher due to error (4/4): Bundler::HTTPError Could not fetch specs from https://rubygems.org/
```

UPDATE:

```
$ bundle
The dependency tzinfo-data (>= 0) will be unused by any of the platforms Bundler is installing for. Bundler is installing for ruby but the dependency is only for x86-mingw32, x86-mswin32, x64-mingw32, java. To add those platforms to the bundle, run `bundle lock --add-platform x86-mingw32 x86-mswin32 x64-mingw32 java`.
Fetching source index from http://rubygems.org/
^CFulls-MacBook-Pro-2:untitled user$ DEBUG_RESOLVER=true DEBUG=1 bundle
Starting resolution (2018-09-25 19:45:02 -0700)
User-requested dependencies: [#<Gem::Resolver::DependencyRequest:0x00007f9333846930 @dependency=<Gem::Dependency type=:runtime name="bundler" requirements="= 1.16.5">, @requester=nil>]
Resolving dependencies...Creating possibility state for bundler (= 1.16.5) (1 remaining)
 Attempting to activate bundler-1.16.5
 Activated bundler at bundler-1.16.5
 Requiring nested dependencies ()

Finished resolution (1 steps) (Took 0.004 seconds) (2018-09-25 19:45:02 -0700)
Unactivated:
Activated: bundler
Running `bundle install` with bundler 1.16.5
Found changes from the lockfile, re-resolving dependencies because the list of sources changed, the dependencies in your gemfile changed
The dependency tzinfo-data (>= 0) will be unused by any of the platforms Bundler is installing for. Bundler is installing for ruby but the dependency is only for x86-mingw32, x86-mswin32, x64-mingw32, java. To add those platforms to the bundle, run `bundle lock --add-platform x86-mingw32 x86-mswin32 x64-mingw32 java`.
HTTP GET http://index.rubygems.org/versions
Net::OpenTimeout: execution expired
```

Comment: Can you try doing this ? replace `source 'https://www.rubygems.org'` to `source 'http://www.rubygems.org'` in your **Gemfile**.

Comment: see result in question

Comment: Also, did you run this command ? `bundle lock --add-platform x86-mingw32 x86-mswin32 x64-mingw32 java`

Answer (score 0):

Few chatters are going now days regarding IPV6 for similar kind of issue.
While gem is stalling, I ran **netstat**

```
netstat -tnp | grep ruby
```

and I got below output

```
(Not all processes could be identified, non-owned process info
 will not be shown, you would have to be root to see it all.)
tcp6       0      1 2401:4900:188e:90:56960 2a04:4e42:600::644:443  SYN_SENT    4096/ruby
```

and 2a04:4e42:600::644:443 is one of the addresses of api.rubygems.org

My conclusion is that gem uses IPv6 when it can.

**So disabling IPV6 on my workstation fixed it.**

Below are the steps to temporarily disabled IPV6 on Ubuntu. IPV6 will be enabled by When we restart system system after restart.

```
sysctl -w net.ipv6.conf.all.disable_ipv6=1
sysctl -w net.ipv6.conf.default.disable_ipv6=1
```

Note: Use sudo for `permission denied` issue.